# tqdm for a For Loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, tqdm

I am using `tqdm` to track progress for a `for` loop in python.

```
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm 

x = np.arange(20000000)

x_30 = []

for _x in tqdm(x):
    x_30.append(_x**30)
```

The progress bar looks like the following.

[image]

Can you please explain the progress bar for me? I don't really understand it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format of the bar is

```
{progress in percentage} | {bar} | {processed}/{total} [{elapsed time}<{remaining time}, {number of iterations per seconds} it/s]
```

You can find further information in the [documentation, under `bar_format`](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/#parameters).